# Position ImageViews relative to each other

Tags: android, imageview, css-position

This has been bugging me for a while. I want to be able to position ImageViews relative to each other in one or another layout, it doesn't really matter which. Note that I cannot use the rules of RelativeLayout for this as what I want to achieve is a bit more complicated. The position of one ImageView is dependent on the position of another ImageView and a given angle. I have tried positioning the first ImageView by itself and then the rest of them relative to the first or another ImageView that is already placed. This is done by overriding the onLayout method in my custom ImageView class like this:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom) {

String uri = "com.foo.bar:dimen/" + size;   
int sizeResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, null);

if ( this.getId() == rel_id ){

//Position this ImageView first, the others relative to this or each other
LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(this.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(sizeResource),
this.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(sizeResource));
//TODO: Remove hard coding
p.topMargin = 10;
p.leftMargin = 10;
this.setLayoutParams(p);

}
else{

//calculate x_position using the ImageView's width, height, leftMargin and a given relative angle
//calculate y_position using the ImageView's width, height, topMargin and a given relative angle

LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(this.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(sizeResource),
this.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(sizeResource));   
p.topMargin = y_position;
p.leftMargin = x_position;
this.setLayoutParams(p);

}

}
```

The problem now is that onLayout gets called twice when it is added to my LinearLayout or RelativeLayout and the widths and heights of each ImageView are different each time and thus the positioning becomes wrong. Has this something to do with onMeasure? How can I work around this problem?

If you have any good sources or explanations on the "Lifecycle" of onMeasure, onLayout, onDraw and so forth, I'll appreaciate it!

Comment: Jest for the reference: [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) page describes some of the details around the lifecycle of Views.